# How much difference does the autoloader make on a tank?

Tags: battlefield-3

I'm just wondering if it really make a difference in a tank to tank encounter.
Its usually which ever tank can get the first shot will prevail unless the other tank can drive, shoot and dodge some shots;
But would the autoloader make a difference in that? how many shot would it take before the autoloader has "given" you an extra shot compared to a tank that doesn't have the autoloader?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a (very) tiny bit of google-ing I came across this video:

It says that the *Autoloader* makes you shoot 0.5 sec faster per shot